# How to compare two variables and set a value of a third variable

Tags: javascript

I have this function I can't seem to get to work. I want it to compare two variables and set the value of a third variable.

```
var win_lose;
var this_roll = $('#past')[0].childNodes[9].textContent;
var last_roll = $('#past')[0].childNodes[9].textContent;

function compare() {

    if (!(this_roll == last_roll)) {
        win_lose = 'lose';
    } else {
        win_lose = 'win';
    }
    console.log(win_lose);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you actually call the function?

```
var this_roll = $('#past')[0].childNodes[9].textContent;
var last_roll = $('#past')[0].childNodes[9].textContent;

function compare(this_roll, last_roll) {
    var win_lose;  //added new variable here
    if (this_roll != last_roll) {
        win_lose = 'lose';
    } else {
        win_lose = 'win';
    }
    return win_lose;
}

var res = compare(this_roll, last_roll);
console.log(res);
```

I also rewrote your if statement, no need to check for equality then invert.

I would also pass parameters in to a function as I have.

Comment: *var* has got function scoping... Also it is part of the global scope, so scoping isnt his problem...

Comment: But does that set the value of the global "win_lose"?

Comment: @cbh1608 no, hence why I edited to include a return.  Don't set global variables from within functions, it can make it very hard to keep track.  Instead make functions return values which in turn can be assigned.

Comment: @Jonasw agreed, I removed the scoping, I have a feeling the function was not called.

Comment: @JonTaylor how would I use the result from this function in another function?

Comment: @cbh1608 as I have at the bottom of the code snippet.  you can store the result of the function in a new variable, in this case I called the variable `res`.  You can call this function from inside another function.